# How to Make Fix Position Like Facebook Promote Side bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-grid

Hello All Brother and Sister!!
I want to Make a Side Bar That We Scroll Down like my Image

[image]

**And Then it Fix Like This**

[image]

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `position: fixed;` this will fix your element so that it will stick to the same spot on the screen